# Objective c - call method on dealloc delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates, dealloc, retaincount

I have an object `Person` and a protocol `PersonDelegate`
`Person` has a `@property (assign) id<PersonDelegate> delegate`;

somewhere in my code I do:

```
Person *newPerson = [[Person alloc] init]; 
newPerson.delegate = theDelegate;  
...  
[theDelegate release]; // and dealloc

...

now Person has some new information for the delegate, so I call in Person
[self.delegate doSomething];
```

But then I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Is this because the delegate was already dealloc? How can Person know that his delegate is dealloc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delegate property is not set to retain so it will go bad as soon as you do `[theDelegate release];`

Normally a delegate *is* set to assign though to avoid a circular reference. But in that case the delegate itself is normally already keeping a reference to the object it is delegated from.

ie.

```
Person *newPerson = [[Person alloc] init]; 
[self.people addObject:newPerson];
newPerson.delegate = self;
[newPerson release];
```

So `self.people` is retaining all the `persons` which are created and those `persons` all point back to `self` as their delegate

Answer (score 1):

You are **assigning** your delegate instead of **retaining** it.
Since you release your delegate it is no longer valid in your person object as it was NOT retained by it.

Change your delegate property to :

`@property (retain) id<PersonDelegate> delegate`;

and dont forget to release it when you dealloc your person object

Comment: well probably because most delegates are view controllers or objects which last more than the object itself. In this case he clearly releases the delegate immediately

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you really want `assign`....  :)

You could save the `newPerson` as a property and set its delegate to nil before the delegate object is released.
You could have a Person object listen for a notification that the delegate is going away and have it set it to nil by itself.

Comment: But why go all the trouble when you can retain it and release it in person's dealloc ?

Comment: I don't know but I suppose there might be reasons that I can't think of.  Why does Apple do it for UIWebViewDelegate?

Comment: And when delegates are `assign`, I believe the programmer is responsible for keeping them alive while they're needed.  If you need to destroy it early, you could use either of the tactics I suggested.